# Is there a way to connect to postgres when have error "sorry, too many clients already "?

Tags: postgresql

I want to see what application is the cause, but even I change to user postgres and run psql, it still throw error

Comment: Could you disconnect current users? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5109190/3270427

Comment: @McNets but how ?, I cannot connect to postgres to run any query

Comment: It sounds you have access to the OS.  If on linux, you can run as `postgres` a variant of `ps fuxwww` to see what's going on.

Comment: @dezso thank you, run `ps fuxwww` as `postgres` I can see all the connection and database. Is there a way I can see more, each connection in my app have `application_name` I want to see it too :)

Comment: I'm afraid you can do that only if you kick a process (using `kill` - be careful _not_ to use `kill -9` as it will stop the whole DB) and quickly log in to the 'slot' made free that way.  Or dig the log files.

Comment: The `superuser_reserved_connections` parameter in configuration normally allows you to set aside some number of connections only for the superuser. The default is 3. Did you change it? Do you connect as superuser?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I don't know about that parameter, it commented in the config, I have uncomment it, so I just `su postgres` and then `psql` and then I will in right ?

Comment: @dezso I guess so, thank you for the help :)

Comment: Yes, by default `postgres` should be the superuser so it should have `superuser_reserved_connections` number of connections available for him, whatever else happens in the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to connect to database any how you need to free some connections on the server

1. Check all the idle postgres connection `ps auxwww|grep 'idle in transaction'` which will return list of all idle transaction processes with pid .
2. kill "pid" e.g say 10544 process having idle connection to database so `kill 10544` will free up a single connection.

Now you can get access to database and check what/whom/when/where is holding your connection using query for monitoring `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;`

It's better to increase `max_connections` of your postgresql server if you have more connections and users.

Just follow below steps

1. First find your `postgresql.conf` file
   If you don't know where it is, query the database with the sql: `SHOW config_file;` 
   Mine is in: `/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf`
2. Login as root and edit that file.
   Search for the string: `max_connections`.
   You'll see a line that says `max_connections=100`
3. Set that number bigger, check the limit for your postgresql version.
4. Restart the postgresql database for the changes to take effect
   `service postgresql restart`.

Comment: You should log in as `postgres` to edit the configuration file, not as `root`

Comment: root(server level user) will also do as later he need to restart postgresql services as well

Comment: I think you should warn a user that restarting postgres will kill all active connections?

Answer (score 5):

## Slots reserved for `postgres` superuser

PostgreSQL reserves a few connections for superusers. If your application is not using superuser connections you can connect as a superuser (eg `postgres`). Then run diagnostic queries like:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

### `superuser_reserved_connections` setting

See the [`superuser_reserved_connections`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html) setting in the Postgres configuration. Defaults to 3 reserved slots.

To quote the version 11 documentation:

> Determines the number of connection “slots” that are reserved for connections by PostgreSQL superusers. At most `max_connections` connections can ever be active simultaneously. Whenever the number of active concurrent connections is at least `max_connections` minus `superuser_reserved_connections`, new connections will be accepted only for superusers, and no new replication connections will be accepted.
>
> The default value is three connections. The value must be less than `max_connections` minus `max_wal_senders`. This parameter can only be set at server start.